# mod_perl basic auth, $r->user() fails

Tags: perl, mod-perl

We have a project that uses `mod_perl2` and mason.

The problem I'm facing is getting the user authenticated using apache basic auth, from .htaccess .

In cgi enviroment I can get that from `$ENV{REMOTE_USER}`

In mod_perl I should be able to get it using `$r->user()`, which unfortunately returns undef.

Also no luck with `$r->connection->user()`

I've also tried `CGI::Apache2::Wrapper`,  `$cgi->remote_user()` and  `$cgi->user_name()` again with no luck.

The only way it works is calling `$r->headers_in->get('Authorization')` which returns something like: '`Basic dGhlZHJpdmVyaXM6eGVudXByZQ==`'

Any ideea why `$r->user()` fails?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have `Apache2::RequestRec` loaded?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes Apache2::RequestRec is loaded

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `$r->user()` is only set when mod_perl2 does the authentication, not when apache does it.

Try adding:

```
my ($res, $sent_pw) = $r->get_basic_auth_pw;
```

above the call to `$r->user()`.  This might trigger the module to decode the Authorization header.

or, you could manually base64 dcode the Authorization header:

```
my $auth = $r->headers_in->get('Authorization');
my $username = (split(/:/,APR::Base64::decode((split(/ /,$auth))[1])))[0];
```